# Erro no carregamento do localhost

Tags: react, react-native

Ao executar meu código react native no simulador do xcode, ele me retorna algum erro no localhost. 
Porem não mexi no código, apenas criei o projeto e executei.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifique as dicas que o próprio error retorna, caso não compreenda inglês use um tradutor. Uma dica seria verificar todos os passos da instalação do react native e seus requisitos.

Comment: Experimente executar assim, abra dois terminais na mesma pasta do projeto e execute o metro separado, primeiro `react-native start ` e no outro terminal `react-native run-ios` e o escolha o emulador de sua preferência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se já resolveu, mas às vezes não é um problema. Às vezes demora fazer o download da aplicação pro simulador e aí ele mostra que deu erro, mas ainda não terminou de receber o app. Veja sua janela do metro bundle. La mostra o carregamento. Muitas vezes também o é só resetar o cache com o comando react-native start --reset-cache na pasta do projeto.